# What are the limitations of the Ebers-Moll model of the BJT

Tags: bjt

The Ebers-Moll model is considered simple yet effective model of the BJT. What makes it special and when does it break down i.e is not applicable?

Comment: The EE equations work for large signals, while for small signals it's better to use the hybrid or Giacoletto's model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original Ebers-Moll model can't capture the [Early Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_effect) or any charge storage effects. It can be modified to include these: [Mathworks NPN enhanced Ebers-Moll model](http://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/elec/ref/npnbipolartransistor.html).

There is also the [Gummel-Poon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gummel%E2%80%93Poon_model) model. It is possible to exactly get the Ebers-Moll model from the Gummel-Poon model by setting certain parameters to a certain value.

According to [this derivation](http://www.ece.umd.edu/class/enee697.S2002/handout/bipolar.handout/EMGPmodel.pdf), Gummel-Poon is able to capture space-charge layer generation/recombination, as well as high-level injection (variation of \$\beta\$ with current?) and the Early effect. I didn't thoroughly look through the differences between the "enhanced Ebers-Moll" and the Gummel-Poon model.